# sess.run() causing training to be slow

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am training a CNN and I believe my use of `sess.run()` is causing my training to be very slow.

In essence, I am use the `mnist` data set...

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
...
...
features = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
```

The issue is, the first layer of the CNN must accept the images in the form of `[batch_size, 28, 28, 1]`, which means I must convert each image before feeding it to the CNN.

I do the following with my script...

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])  
...
...
with tf.Session() as sess:

    for epoch in range(25):

        total_batch = int(features.train.num_examples/500)

        avg_cost = 0

        for i in range(total_batch):

            batch_xs, batch_ys = features.train.next_batch(10)

            # Notice this line.
            _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x:sess.run(tf.reshape(batch_xs, [10, 28, 28, 1])), y:batch_ys})

            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        if (epoch + 1) % 1 == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
```

Notice the commented line. I am taking the first batch from the training set and I am reshaping to the proper format `[batch_size, 28, 28, 1]`. I have to call `sess.run()` every single time and I believe this is the cause for the training to be so slow.

How can I prevent this. I tried reformatting the data in another script using `numpy`, but it still gave me issues because I cannot feed the `numpy` array without running `sess.run()`. Can someone show me how to format the data outside of the training session? Maybe I can format the data in another script and load it into the one containing my CNN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely not have the inner `sess.run()` on new ops at each iteration (though I'm not sure how much it really slows you down). You should do one of these:

- have a placeholder of the same shape as your input, e.g. `[None, 28*28*1]`, followed by a `tf.reshape([None, 28, 28, 1])`, at the beginning of your network (instead of your  `tf.placeholder([None, 28, 28, 1])`)

OR

- Keep your neural network, and reformat using numpy reshape instead of tensorflow: `_, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x:batch_xs.reshape( [-1, 28, 28, 1]), y:batch_ys})`

It probably also works if you just write  `_, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x:tf.reshape(batch_xs, [10, 28, 28, 1]), y:batch_ys})` but you should *not* do that, since it creates a new op in your graph at each iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it slows down the network either, but I implemented the second approach and the training seems to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing you can do is reshape all the inputs in the beginning itself and then feed it to the placeholder.

```
import math
import numpy as np
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])  
...
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    X_train=mnist.train.images.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
    y_train=mnist.train.labels
    train_indicies = np.arange(X_train.shape[0])
    num_epochs = 25 // number of epochs
    batch_size = 50
    total_batch = int(math.ceil(X_train.shape[0]/batch_size))
    for epoch in range(25):
        for i in np.arange(total_batch):
        start_idx = (i*batch_size)%X_train.shape[0]
        idx = train_indicies[start_idx:start_idx+batch_size]
        _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x:X_train[idx,:], y:y_train[idx]})
        avg_cost += c / total_batch

    if (epoch + 1) % 1 == 0:
        print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
```

since we will not be able to use mnist.train.next_batch, we will need to manually calculate and increment the indices.

Hope this works :)